# Adding an image to a header in LaTeX

Tags: graphics, header-footer

Is there a way to add a header image in LaTeX that spans the entire page and ignores margins? I tried

```
\lhead{\includegraphics{image.png}}
```

But this considers margins, and so I still get a lot of whitespace at the top of the page. So, is there a way to have these images ignore whitespace?

Comment: Correct if I'm wrong, you want an image to span from your header upwards, I assume as wide as the page, right?

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276358/text-on-background-image-footer-and-header/276453?s=4|0.9641#276453

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

[image: Big header]

I let `tikzpagenodes` do the math so that you can change all the settings you want in `geometry` and `fancyhdr` such as `top` or `headersep` and so on. You will need to compile twice:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[left=4cm,top=10cm,right=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\lhead{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw  let \p1=($(current page.north)-(current page header area.south)$),
      \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
node [inner sep=0,outer sep=0,below right] 
      at (current page.north west){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\n1]{img}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
Type your document as usual!
\newpage
\section{Second section}
Type your document as usual!
\end{document}
```

I had trouble finding the distance between the header text and the headrule, so I've zeroed its thickness as I thought you won't need it.

Comment: Glad that you like it!

Answer (score 0):

I tried adjusting the left header width to various values and all of them worked for me. You can tweak this to suit you needs.

*(Adjusting both the image width and height at the same time is a bad idea, and highly discouraged. This was  done here for experimental purposed only.)*

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth,height=5.0mm]{latex.png}}

\setlength{\headheight}{7.50mm}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Short Width Left Header}

\lipsum[1-5]

\clearpage

\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=0.50\textwidth,height=5.0mm]{latex.png}}

\section{Mid Width Left Header}

\lipsum[1-5]

\clearpage

\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=1.00\textwidth,height=5.0mm]{latex.png}}

\section{Full Width Left Header}

\lipsum[1-5]


\end{document}
```

---

[image]

[image]

[image]