# Make headers with a predetermined image

Tags: header-footer

I'm writing a book in LaTeX and I need to do the headers with the publisher's stye.  That styles uses an image in every header but with two different texts: the even pages contain the title of the book and the odd pages contain the title of the chapter. It's something like this
[image: The sample that I need to imitate]
[image: The sample that I need to imitate]

And this what I have for now.
[image: What I have for now]
[image]

How can I make the headers with an predertmined image but with different texts depending on the chapter?

This is a MWE of my book.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,reqno]{book}
\listfiles
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[spanish,es-nosectiondot]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{infwarerr}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{verbatim} %Para comentar bloques de texto
\usepackage[text={168mm,240mm},centering]{geometry}%Define el ancho y la    altura del texto (Página)
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{epsfig,graphicx,psfrag,float}
\usepackage{ltxcmds}
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,pst-math,pst-xkey,pst-pdf,auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{tocloft}% Este paquete modifica los parámetros de la Tabla de   Contenidos (ToC)
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeindex

\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Capítulo }
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnumb}{\\ }
\renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{0mm}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{Algebra}{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Prefacio}
\include{EnsayoPrefacio}
\include{Ensayos}
\include{Index}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please add a minimal working example. The answer highly depends on your code.

Comment: This is a MWE of my book.

Comment: For really fancy headers, you need to use everypage and tikz.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276358/text-on-background-image-footer-and-header/276453?s=3|0.2042#276453 for example.

Comment: Crosspost  http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=29954&p=101262#p101262

Comment: It is unacceptable to see that you a) don't openly show your crossposts and b) you don't update your question with the info gained at the other site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

everybody. I've been making several mistakes everytime I participate in this forum.  I'm sorry about that.

The solution to my problem was to introduce and edit this code:

```
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{Algebra}
\fancyhead[LE]{\makebox[0pt][l]{%
\hspace{-4em}\raisebox{-1ex}{\includegraphics[height=4ex]{foo-p1}}%
}\thepage}
\fancyhead[RO]{\makebox[0pt][l]{%
\hspace{-0.5em}\raisebox{-1ex}{\includegraphics[height=4ex]{foo-p1}}%
}\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\makebox[0pt][l]{%
\hspace{-4em}\raisebox{-1ex}{\includegraphics[height=4ex]{foo-p2}}%
}\leftmark}
\renewcommand*\headrulewidth{0pt}
\renewcommand*\footrulewidth{0pt}
```

This was supplied in [latex.org forum](http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=29954).

I just added the gray bars with \includegraphics and edited the vertical position.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got a solution.  This topic was posted in other forum and there I was [given the solution](http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=29954). Someone gave this code and I just had to edit it a little bit.

```
\listfiles % the usual place for \listfiles is here: above \documentclass. Easier to cleanup after troubleshooting all the issues, IMHO.
\documentclass[letterpaper,reqno]{book}
\usepackage[spanish,es-nosectiondot]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[text={168mm,240mm},centering]{geometry}
\usepackage{%epsfig,<-- do you really need that?
  graphicx%,psfrag,float
}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{Algebra}
\fancyhead[LE]{\makebox[0pt][l]{%
  \hspace{-4em}\raisebox{-1ex}{\includegraphics[height=4ex]{foo-p1}}%
  }\thepage}
\fancyhead[RO]{\makebox[0pt][l]{%
  \hspace{-0.5em}\raisebox{-1ex}{\includegraphics[height=4ex]{foo-p1}}%
  }\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\makebox[0pt][l]{%
  \hspace{-4em}\raisebox{-1ex}{\includegraphics[height=4ex]{foo-p2}}%
  }\leftmark}
\renewcommand*\headrulewidth{0pt}
\renewcommand*\footrulewidth{0pt}
\begin{document}
  \Blinddocument
  \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Thanks for everything.  This topic can be considered closed.

Comment: You should attribute the code to its author and provide a link. Mere basic courtesy.

Comment: You are right and I apologize.  This solution was given by **rais** and this is the links where you can see it http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=29954

Comment: Please add that to your answer. Comments are not permanent.