# Please help in designing a template for a short communications journal

Tags: templates, journal

I want to design a template for a short communications journal (for the actual journal output, not articles inside). It should have two column content with text+images in each column and sometimes two column images. Full banner header and footer with no margin (the content will have a small margin) including text over image like [Text on background-image footer and header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276358/text-on-background-image-footer-and-header). The page itself needs to have a background (may be that can include the header and footer banners too? like in [How to use background image in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167719/how-to-use-background-image-in-latex) so that no special formatting is required).

Any idea about this will be most welcome.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you after something for the cover page? What have you tried?

Comment: All pages are same with header and footer and background. I have tried to make with a background image and everything overlayed.