# Different headers for odd and even pages of onesided layout without fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

I am using the `oneside` layout of [MastersDoctoralThesis](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis). I want to give a different header for even and odd pages. The process should be simple with `fancyhdr`, however it not supported in this template, unfortunately.
This is so far I've come across:

```
\clearpairofpagestyles
\cehead{even header}
\cohead{odd header}
```

However, it prints "odd header" on ALL the pages and ignores my `cehead` command.

Comment: There are, by definition, no odd and even pages when using a one-sided layout ... Use a two-sided one.

Comment: You can create your own headers using everypage and tikzpagenodes.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276358/text-on-background-image-footer-and-header/276453?r=SearchResults&s=10|18.7871#276453

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned in a comment, there are only recto (odd) pages in onesided documents. But you could use

```latex
\clearpairofpagestyles
\chead{%
  \ifodd\number\value{page}
    odd header%
  \else
    even header%
  \fi
}
```

to get different headers for even and odd pages in your document.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[oneside]{MastersDoctoralThesis}% loads package scrlayer-scrpage
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

\clearpairofpagestyles
\chead{%
  \ifodd\number\value{page}
    odd header%
  \else
    even header%
  \fi
}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image]